# Query to select distinct nodes

Tags: .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I need to write a LINQ to XML query to select list of User Nodes who have distinct ID , here the attribute ID is in every User Node

Comment: You could at least show us your xml example...

Answer (score 0):

The following query

```
var grouping = elements.GroupBy(e => (string)e.Attribute("ID")));
```

will group selected elements by attribute ID.

---

Or you need IDs only? Distinct?

```
var ids = elements.Select(e => (string)e.Attribute("ID")).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xmlSource = contacts.Load(@"../../Contacts.xml");


var q = from c in xmlSource.User
        where c.ID in (from c2 in xlsource.User select c.id ).distict().tolist()
        select c;
```

you have to do something like this